# Where can I find Network Manager VPN connections files in a Debian 8 Jessie installation?

Tags: networking, gnome, openvpn, networkmanager, debian-jessie

I had some vpn connections configured through network manager on a Debian 8 Jessie installation and I want to copy them to another fresh install of the same OS.y

On the old install I used the default gnome's network manager with network-manager-openvpn-gnome for setting up vpn connections.

I want to know where can I find the config files ( and/or any other files ) so that I can copy them on my new install and use the vpn connections right away.

Thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1480826 probably answers your questions.

In short, check:
/etc/NetworkManager
~/.gconf/system/networking/connections